# django ping google http error

Tags: django, ping, http-error

I'm trying to ping Google, but get HTTP Error. Why?
env/bin/python manage.py ping_google [/sitemap.xml]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/wen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/wen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/wen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/var/www/wen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/management/commands/ping_google.py", line 13, in execute
    ping_google(sitemap_url=sitemap_url)
  File "/var/www/wen/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py", line 37, in ping_google
    urlopen("%s?%s" % (ping_url, params))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Site map I did it myself.

Comment: have you registered your site with google webmaster tools as it says to do here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.ping_google

Comment: @StuartLeigh My site is added to webmaster tools day ago.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `[` and `]`? So that it would be `env/bin/python manage.py ping_google "/sitemap.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `python manage.py '/sitemap.xml'` and I got no error